# Access the Contract State within the Notary

Tags: state, corda, notary

I want to trigger a transaction in an External network from the Notary Service Flow just before consuming the Input State. The example is a Custodian service that triggers the notification to the Depository: Custodian on Corda & Depository on Hedera Hashgraph.

But the Notary flow does not have access to read the attributes from the Contract State. Is there a way to send/broadcast custom attributes to the Notary?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your notary as a validating one; it will have access to all of the transaction components (read [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/key-concepts-notaries.html#validation)).

To setup your notary as validating; set the below configuration inside its `node.conf` (taken from [this sample](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-configuration-file.html#configuration-examples)):

```
notary {
    validating = true
}
```